# How do you display multiple combo box items in one text box?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo with multiple selections enabled. I've made a new form, and want to display the combo box selections in a text box. I use the following to display the actual data instead of the key: `=[MyComboBox].[Column](2)` but it only displays the data where there is exactly 1 item selected in the record. For records where there are multiple items selected in the combo box it displays nothing.

How can I display all my selections in the text box?

Comment: Loop the `SelectedItems` of the Combox and concatenate them in the textbox. But why not replace this with a listbox?

Comment: @Gustav Because I'm a noob and don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListBox and create a function like:

```vb
    Public Function GetSelectedItems(list As ListBox, Optional index as int = 0) As String
        Dim result As String

        For Each varItem In list.ItemsSelected
            result = result & "," & combo.Column(index)
        Next

        GetSelectedItems = Mid(result, 2)
    End Function
```

Assign the result of this function to text box:

```vb
    Me.MyTextBox = GetSelectedItems(Me.MyComboBox, 2)
```